# SNS send push twice

Tags: ios, node.js, push-notification, amazon-sns

I'm using `SNS` to send push to `18000` devices. But sometimes I get 2 notifications when using `SNS`.

I use `NodeJS AWS SDK` to call the `SNS.publish` function

```
...

getAlldevices(query, function(){
    console.log(devices.length) # prints 18000
    let sent = 0;
    devices.forEach(function(device){
         SNSPUsh.send(message, device); # this function calls sns.publish
         sent++;
         console.log(sent);
    });
    console.log(sent++); # print 18000
});
```

in the logs I see the following

```
18000
1
2
.
.
.
18000
18000
```

So no duplication in the logs/console

But sometime (not everytime) i get the push twice and I checked the `CloudWatch NumberOfMessagesPublished` and it shows that it published `36000`. I'm not publishing to a topic so there is no retry policy.

I'm using this [module (but without parse)](https://github.com/benishak/parse-server-sns-adapter/blob/master/src/SNSPushAdapter.js)

Comment: could be event publisher issue ,your publisher might be publishing twice